# Using AWK to monitor changing values every 60 seconds

Tags: awk

Does any one have an easy way of doing this using `awk`, maybe associative arrays?

One other thing is there is a delay of 60 seconds between these two input streams and any time a value on the right hand side changes I will take an appropriate action. These two input streams are output from a system command and not files.

Input 1:

```
Direct Reads      1000023
Sequential Scans  2043
Table Scans       32749
```

Input2:

```
Direct Reads      1005679
Sequential Scans  2043
Table Scans       32749
```

Desired output:

```
Changed monitor element
Direct Reads: Increased by 5656 in 60 seconds.
```

Comment: Can you show a little more of what you've done so far? It's a little confusing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is that a single command producing output every minute, or do you run the command once per minute?

Answer (score 1):

```
your_command | awk '
    {label = substr($0,1,18); value = substr($0,19)} 
    !(label in data) {data[label] = value; time[label] = systime(); next} 
    value != data[label] {
        print "Changed monitor element";
        deltav = value - data[label]
        deltat = systime() - time[label]
        how = delta < 0 ? "Decreased" : "Increased" 
        printf "%s: %s by %d in %d seconds\n", label, how, deltav, deltat
    }
'
```